# What causes the long tiredness caused by the infectious mononucleosis disease (by the Epstein-Barr virus)?

Tags: infection, fatigue, cause-and-effect, mononucleosis

Of course to cure from a fever in general takes already time to recover from, but in the kissing disease it takes often much longer (sometimes even years) and the tiredness is much more a symptom of the Epstein virus than other virus infections. But what causes this precisely?

Comment: The premise of this question is somewhat incorrect. EBV does not cause more post-infection symptoms than every other viral infection. There are some viral (and some bacterial) infections that [are comparable](https://www.bmj.com/content/333/7568/575) in this regard. So I suspect the mechanisms are somewhat non-specific.

Comment: I'm not sure how the numbers compare precisely/directly, but SARS and Covid-19 also cause such fatigue. For SARS it was something like 25% of those infected who experienced post-viral fatigue https://www.kcl.ac.uk/coronavirus-why-are-some-people-experiencing-long-term-fatigue

Comment: Likewise for Ebola, some 28% reported such post-infection fatigue. The incidence from EBV seems somewhat lower at 4-13% (depending on the time frame) https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/21641846.2020.1778227

Answer (score 1):

There is no consensus on the exact cause, although in Chronic Epstein-Barr Activation (CEBA) it has been linked to the effects of inflammation (eg a cytokine storm), plus immune activation and [tryptophan degradation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165032707003321).

In the more common, non-CEBA Epstein-Barr infection immune system responses are also suggested to be linked to the fatigue.
*"Presently, therefore the is no proven fatigue-causing substance or fatigue transmitting substance.
However, the most probable candidates for such fatigue-inducing or fatigue transmitting substances are cytokines, including interferon."*[2](http://www.med.or.jp/english/pdf/2006_01/027_033.pdf)

Lasting fatigue is found in a number of viruses, including a number of Covid-19 patients.[3](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12974-017-0796-7) This may be related to Interleukin-1 levels, an inflammatory cytokine.

Long term fatigue is often termed "Chronic fatigue", "post-fatigue infection" or "post-viral fatigue" (without the syndrome part).

Comment: It's important to note that Chronic active Epstein-Barr virus (CAEBV) infection is a rare and life-threatening condition where the virus is never brought under control. 

Also I agree that Long term fatigue = Chronic fatigue, but long term fatigue is not synonymous with post-infectious fatigue/post-viral fatigue. CFS is considered a type of post-infectious fatigue though according to your 2nd source.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Emedicine medscape](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/222040-differential):

> Appreciate that EBV may trigger chronic fatigue, but it does not cause chronic fatigue.

In their page on [Chronic Fatigue Syndrome](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/235980-overview#a4):

> CFS is a biological illness, not a psychologic disorder. The **exact pathogenesis is unknown**. Numerous mechanisms and molecules have been implicated that lead to abnormalities in immune dysfunction, hormonal regulation, metabolism and response to oxidative stress to include impaired natural killer cell function and/or T-cell function, elevated cytokines, and autoantibodies (rheumatic factor, antithyroid antibodies, antigliadin, anti–smooth muscle antibodies, and cold agglutinins). [3, 4] Infections have been suspected; however, no causal role has been established.

The sources cited:

3. https://www.cdc.gov/me-cfs/index.html
4. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28760971

Comment: The question asked about tiredness in EBV, not cases of CFS resulting from EBV. CFS cannot be diagnosed until after the virus has cleared.

Comment: I agree with you that CFS is something that would occur after an EBV infection resolves. I had interpreted the questions as asking for a reason for long-term tiredness after an EBV infection.